# Construct a PHP curl statement from cURL cli syntax

Tags: php, curl

**Here is my functioning *cURL* syntax (placeholder #'s in place of valid id's for security):**

```
curl -H "Accept: text/xml" https://111222333444555:99999888887777755555@www.sendowl.com/api/v1/products
```

**I get a valid xml response back:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><products><product><created-at>2015-08-06T20:51:19Z</created-at>....
```

**Here is what my PHP syntax currently looks like:**

```
<?php

//Initialize curl object
$ch = curl_init();

$apikey = "111222333444555";
$apisecret = "99999888887777755555";
$uri = "https://$apikey:$apisecret@www.sendowl.com/api/v1/products";
echo $uri;
//Define curl options in an array
$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => $uri,
                 CURLOPT_HEADER => "Accept: text/xml",
                 CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
                 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
);

//Set options against curl object
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

//Assign execution of curl object to a variable
$data = curl_exec($ch);

//Close curl object
curl_close($ch);

echo ("data is: $data");
//Pass results to the SimpleXMLElement function
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

print_r($xml);

?>
```

**It would seem `$data` is always null, and I get the following error as a result:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in C:\xampp\htdocs\whd.com\license.php:27 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\whd.com\license.php(27): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\whd.com\license.php on line 27
```

Comment: if (FALSE === $data)
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));

tells me there's a problem with my SSL certificate on my localhost/apache test server.  Guess I'll try to create a certificate and see what happens.  Any way around this?

Comment: You can tell `curl` to ignore certificate problems by setting the options `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar enough with stack overflow to know if this the correct way to help but:

`CURLOPT_HEADER => "Accept: text/xml"`

should be

`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Accept: text/xml')`